# iText PDF document failing to open: java.io.IOException: No message found for the.document.has.no.pages

Tags: java, pdf, itext

So I am practicing with iText to create a small document. The pdf is created in my downloads folder but when I try to open it I get a message and an error:

**Message:**

`it is either not a support file or it has been damaged`

**Trace:**

```
ExceptionConverter: java.io.IOException: No message found for the.document.has.no.pages
at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfPages.writePageTree(Unknown Source)
at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfWriter.close(Unknown Source)
at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfDocument.close(Unknown Source)
at com.lowagie.text.Document.close(Unknown Source)
at iTextTester.tester.main(tester.java:26)
```

**Code:**

```
    package iTextTester;

import com.lowagie.text.Anchor;
import com.lowagie.text.Chapter;
import com.lowagie.text.Document;
import com.lowagie.text.DocumentException;
import com.lowagie.text.Font;
import com.lowagie.text.Paragraph;
import com.lowagie.text.Section;
import com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfWriter;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;

public class tester {

    private static Font catFont = new Font(Font.TIMES_ROMAN, 18, Font.BOLD);
    private static Font subFont = new Font(Font.TIMES_ROMAN, 12, Font.BOLD);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Document document = new Document();
            PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("C:/Users/me/Downloads/FirstPdf.pdf"));
            document.open();
            document.addTitle("TITLE");
            document.addAuthor("AUTHOR");
            document.close();
            addContent(document);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private static void addContent(Document document) throws DocumentException {
        Anchor anchor = new Anchor("First Chapter", catFont);
        anchor.setName("First Chapter");
         Chapter catPart = new Chapter(new Paragraph(anchor), 1);
        Paragraph subPara = new Paragraph("Subcategory 1", subFont);
        Section subCatPart = catPart.addSection(subPara);
        subCatPart.add(new Paragraph("Hello"));
    }

}
```

Any idea what I am doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was following a very poor tutorial, and found a better one [here](http://www.itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=19).

This code is simplified and works well:

```
    package iTextTester;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import com.lowagie.text.Document;
import com.lowagie.text.DocumentException;
import com.lowagie.text.PageSize;
import com.lowagie.text.Paragraph;
import com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfWriter;

public class tester {

    public static final String RESULT = "C:/Users/me/Downloads/text.pdf";
public static void main(String[] args) throws DocumentException,
        IOException {
    new tester().createPdf(RESULT);
}

public void createPdf(String filename) throws DocumentException,
        IOException {
    Document document = new Document(PageSize.LETTER);
    PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(filename));
    document.open();
    document.add(new Paragraph("Hello World!"));
    document.close();
}
```

}